# Duplicate ids is test class execution

Tags: apex, unit-test

Following in my class. I get duplicate ids in test class execution.

```
// Class 

public class CreateEmpData {    

    public CreateEmpData() { }        

    public static List<Employment_Data__c> list_emp = new List<Employment_Data__c>();
    public static List<Employment_Data__c> list_emp1 = new List<Employment_Data__c>();

    public static httpresponse insertEmpData(){    

        Employment_Data__c empData;
        Employment_Data__c empData1;       


                    list_emp.add(empData);
                }
                else
                {


                    list_emp1.add(empData1);        
                } 

                }              
            }                  
            return res; 

        }

        public static httpresponse insertEmpDataTwo(){

        Integer Year = Date.Today().Year();
        DateTime d = datetime.now();
        String currentMonth = d.format('MMMMM');


        Employment_Data__c empData_one;
        Employment_Data__c empData1_two;
        List<Employment_Data__c> list_emp_two = new List<Employment_Data__c>();
        List<Employment_Data__c> list_emp1_two = new List<Employment_Data__c>();

                    list_emp_two.add(empData_one);
                }
                else
                {


                    list_emp1_two.add(empData1_two);        
                }                 
                }              
            }
            insert list_emp1;
            update list_emp;      
            insert list_emp1_two;
            update list_emp_two;
            return res; 

        }
}

// Schedule class

global class ScheduleEmpData implements Schedulable,Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.AllowsCallouts 
{
    public void execute(SchedulableContext sc){

        Database.executeBatch(new ScheduleEmpData());
    } 

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

        return null;            
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope)
    {

        CreateEmpData.insertEmpData();
        CreateEmpData.insertEmpDataTwo();    
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    { 
    }
}

// Test class

@isTest(SeeAllData=true)

public class TestEmpData{

    public TestEmpData(){
    }

    static testMethod void test(){

        Test.startTest();
        Database.QueryLocator QL;
        Database.BatchableContext BC;
        List<Account> AcctList = new List<Account>();
        ScheduleEmpData SE = new ScheduleEmpData();
        QL = SE.start(bc);

        Database.QueryLocatorIterator QIT =  QL.iterator();
        while (QIT.hasNext())
        {
            Account Acc = (Account)QIT.next();            
            System.debug(Acc);
            AcctList.add(Acc);
        } 

        System.debug('Total Account:'+AcctList.size());

        SE.execute(null);
        SE.execute(BC, AcctList);
        SE.finish(BC);                

        List<Account> acct = [SELECT Id, Name, Service_ID__c FROM Account WHERE Service_ID__c != Null];                

        System.debug(' Account lists:'+acct.size());
        List<Id> ids = new List<Id>(); 
        for(Account a : acct){
            ids.add(a.Id);
        } 

        System.debug(' Total Ids:'+ids.size());

        CreateEmpData ced = new CreateEmpData();
        Database.executeBatch(SE);

       CreateEmpData.insertEmpData();

        //Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new ExampleCalloutMock());        
        //HttpResponse res = CreateEmpData.insertEmpData();

        Test.stopTest();        
    }
}
```

Give me some idea please,

Comment: what have you tried? Where is the error? Posting bunch of code and saying "help me" will not help you. You have to help us to help you

Comment: i have paste my full test class. i get error at update list_emp; statement in my class. System.ListException: Duplicate id in list: a0QK0000004UHXSMA4 when i update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the CreateEmpData class holds the data in static lists, any values added to the lists remain there unless explicitly removed.

The method CreateEmpData.insertEmpData() is called via the Database.executeBatch and then you explicitly call it again immediately after that call, resulting an an insert being done (eventually) for an object that already has an ID (because the object has already been inserted) which is not allowed.

Writing classes that hold static collections is a bad idea. Make those collections local variables in the static methods instead.

Your test contains a lot of code that probably should not be there. (And your CreateEmpData class appears to have lines missing.)